# ZF2: Accessing method from different class from within a class

Tags: php, zend-framework2

in a class 'Event', I want to assign the variable 'customername' from my class 'Customer' to one of the class' variables. My class CustomerTable has a method called 'getCustomer' that creates an instance of Customer by passing a customerId. I want to call that method from within my Event class so I can take the customer name from that customer and assign it to Event.

I've tried making Event extend AbstractActionController and using the service manager to get the method, as you can see in the example below. But when I try to call get() on my CustomerTable class, a message is triggered that says I'm trying to call get() on a non-object.

Basically: does anyone know how I can call getCustomer() from within my Event class?

My Event class as I figured it:

```
class Event
{
    public $id;
    public $CCID;
    public $customerName;   
    public $jobId;
    public $timeServer;
    public $timeConvert;
    public $messageId;
    public $message = null;
    public $severity;
    public $client;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id       = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->CCID     = (isset($data['CCID'])) ? $data['CCID'] : null;
        // here's the stuff that tries to get the getCustomer() method
        $sm                 = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $customer            = $sm->get('Admin\Model\CustomerTable')->getCustomer($this->CCID);
        $this->customerName = $customer->customerName;
        $this->jobId    = (isset($data['jobId'])) ? $data['jobId'] : null;
        $this->timeServer   = (isset($data['TimeServer'])) ? $data['TimeServer'] : null;
        $this->messageId    = (isset($data['messageId'])) ? $data['messageId'] : null;
        $this->severity     = (isset($data['Severity'])) ? $data['Severity'] : null;
        $this->client       = (isset($data['Client'])) ? $data['Client'] : null;
        $this->timeConvert  = gmdate("H:i", $this->timeServer);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try including the AbstractActionController file when you did Event extend AbstractActionController? maybe it didn't work because of that?

Comment: Ever thought about injecting the classes that you need into your Model? Furthermore, do not inject the `ServiceLocator`, **only inject the `CustomerTable`**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples how you can load the class:

```
use \Admin\Model\CustomerTable; // use namespaces
$sm = new CustomerTable();
$customer = $sm->getCustomer($this->CCID);
```

or do it like

```
$sm = new \Admin\Model\CustomerTable\Tidy();
$customer = $sm->getCustomer($this->CCID);
```